# Populate select tag with $ngresource promise Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, ngresource

I have a select on page that i want to populate with data which i get from a server. I'm using service to retrieve this records but how can I access to those values from promise and put them in ng-option of select tag?

**Get data from resource:**

```
  $scope.categories = Category.all({sorting:"asc"});
```

**Resource:**

```
factory('Category', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('api/categories/:id', {}, {
        all: {method: "GET", isArray: true, params: {sorting: '@sorting'}},
        update: {
            method: "PUT",
            params: {
                id: "@id"
            }
        }
    })
}).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `Category.all()` should return an array that will be filled with the retrieved values when the respective http request returns. If you want to run some code on completion, you can pass a callback like this:

```
$scope.categories = Category.all({sorting:"asc"}, function() {
    // do something with the $scope.categories
});
```

You can also obtain a promise like this:

```
$scope.categories = Category.all({sorting:"asc"})
    .$promise.then(function(categories) {
        // do something with the categories
    });
```